# Python | how to print multiple rows of alphabet?

Tags: python

I am trying to get multiple lines of the alphabet but it isn't working. At the moment I have 1 row but it won't work.

What I'm after is once the alphabet gets from `a` to `z`, it will add another letter on until `aa` to `zz` and on and on.

As Requested, the code I currently have is as follows:

```
import string

alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
for i in alphabets:
    print(i)
    alphabets = string.ascii_lowercase
    if i == 'z':
        for b in alphabets:
            print('{}{}'.format(b, b))
            print('{}{}'.format(b, b))
```

Comment: Can you share what have you got now? You should edit your question to include what you have tried.

Comment: Do you want `aa`, `ab`, `ac` ... `zz`? Or `aa`, `bb`, `cc` ... `zz`?

Comment: Are you trying to generate [permutations](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)? Your question is very unclear. Consider giving an example of the output you're looking for with the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using nested for loops.  The outer for loop will iterate through the alphabet, while the outer defines the number of times you want to add a given letter.  Note that some string s times some integer i duplicates that string i times.  This gives us:

```
for i in range(...) #However many instances of the alphabet you want
    for j in range(26)
        print(chr(ord('a')+j)*i)
```

EDIT:  The answer above gives 'a'-'z', followed by 'aa', 'bb', ..., 'zz', etc, which is not what was being looked for.

Instead, we will construct an array and iterate through it in reverse.  The code I came up with is kind of ugly, but it works.  Apologies for the last line in particular.

```
def checkArr(arr):
    for i in arr:
        if i != 25:
            return True
    return False

arr = []
for i in range(5):
    arr = []
    for j in range(i+1):
        arr.append(0)
    while(checkArr(arr)):
        s = ""
        for j in arr:
            s += chr(j + ord("a"))
        print(s)
        index = len(arr)-1
        while (index > 0 and arr[index] == 25):
            arr[index] = 0
            index -= 1
        arr[index] += 1
    print("z"*(i+1))
```

Comment: Hey, when i used your code, it just uses the same letter next to eachother like aaaa, bbbb, cccc. I was after it to go through on each row like okhm pgjy, ect         Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I must have misunderstood your question, I thought that's what you were looking for for some reason.  There are a few ways to solve that; I'll edit my answer above.